# Why currentUser is null while isSignedIn works perfect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I implemented google signIn in Provider pattern, the signIn, signOut and isSignedIn work perfectly but currentUser is always null. Why?

```
class LoginController with ChangeNotifier {
  var _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
    'email'
  ]);

  GoogleSignInAccount? get currentUser {
    return _googleSignIn.currentUser;
  }

  Future<GoogleSignInAccount?> signIn() async {
    try {
      _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And in UI I use:

```
var user = Provider.of<LoginController>(context, listen: false).currentUser;

bool isSignedIn = await Provider.of<LoginController>(context,listen: false).isSignedIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `listen: true` to enable a rebuild on the widget when `currentUser` is set:

```
var user = Provider.of<LoginController>(context, listen: true).currentUser;

print("user is " + (user == null ? "not set" : "set"));
```

Comment: currentUser is a getter, so should it matter if listen is true or false? it'll run the getter method again when currentUser is called. I think that, listen being false, it just doesn't trigger a rebuild.

Comment: No, listen: true did not work.  I don't know what you mean about run the getter method again.  The user is logged until I signout, even remain loggedIn when restart the application. So the problem is that the currentUSer is always null, not the state is not refreshimg.

Comment: Maybe you call it not in the widgets build function?